# Using Perl, how to search a string then add a distinct line of string after it?

Tags: perl, scripting

I am having a little bit of trouble with Perl. Desperate on how to do this very simple search then add a new line after the match.

For example, in my file I will search for a recurring string called "TSET" then after that line I will have to add a distinct label say "tset0:" (in a new line of course) and it needs to increment for the next match it will add "tset1:" but it is always the same search string "TSET".

the file looks like this:

```
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 1XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  000 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 011 XXX XX   ; }

//       pattern 0
W "tset1";
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  XXXXXX  110 011 XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  011000  111 011 XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  000000  111 011 XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 1XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  000 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 011 XXX XX   ; }

//       pattern 0
W "tset1";
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  XXXXXX  110 011 XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  011000  111 011 XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  000000  111 011 XXX XX   ; }
```

so after each W "tset1"; i need to add a new line:
Pattern0:

thanks in advance for the hints.

Comment: It will help if you show some example lines from your file and then an example of what you want it to look like. Lastly show any attempt at code you have tried

Comment: @ChrisDoyle thanks for the reply. my code only tries to count this string i want to search but no working attempt to try and add a new line after the search... i am so noob with Perl. sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using unix based server then this can be written in a one liner.

```
cat test_file.txt | perl -ne 'print /^(W "tset1";)$/ ? "$1\npattern" . $count++ . ":\n" : "$_"'
```

However for better layout and with comments i have placed in a script

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#take the file name from input and open it and initalise the counter as 0
my $file = shift || die "you need to give an input file";
open (my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Unable to open $file: $!";
my $count = 0;

#process each line and if the line matches our pattern tag on a new line and the pattern task to it otherwise just print the normal line.
while (<$fh>){
        print /^(W "tset1";)$/ ? "$1\npattern" . $count++ . ":\n" : "$_";
}
```

Comment: hi @chrisDoyle thanks, this is also an awesome solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your description is rather unclear - are you searching for tset or TSET? Are you replacing it with tset0 or Pattern0?

But this seems simple enough. You should be able to adjust this to your needs.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $count = 0;

while (<>) {
  if (/TSET/) {
    print "Pattern$count:\n"
    ++$count;
  }
  print;
}
```

It reads from STDIN and writes to STDOUT. So you can call it like this:

```
$ ./this_script.pl < your_input.dat > new_version.dat
```

Comment: hi @DaveCross sorry for the confusion. based on the exmaple given, I am actually searching for the W "tset1" statement ALWAYS. then will add a new line below it:
Pattern0:

then for the next match it will be Pattern1:

Comment: Then I think it's trivial for you to change my program to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag to determine whether previously traversed line contained desired string, then use conditionals.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $flag;
while (<DATA>){
    chomp;
    print $_;
    $flag = 0;
    if ($_ =~ /TSET/){
        $flag = 1;
    }
    print "\ntset0:\n" if $flag;
}

__DATA__
lorem posum lorem posum lorem posum TSET lorem posu
lorem posulorem posu lorem posulorem posu lorem posu
lorem posuTSET
```

Answer (score 0):

I have copied given content of your file to a text file locally in my PC and executed below script.

```
#!C:\Strawberry\perl\bin
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = "C:/Users/hclabv/Desktop/Data.txt";

#Opening file to get the required data

my $pattern = 0;
open (FILE, "$file");
     while (<FILE>) {
           my $CurrentLine = $_;

#Creating new file
           open (FILE1, ">>NewData.txt");
           print FILE1 "$CurrentLine";
                if ($_ =~ /tset/) {
                    my $NewLine = "Pattern $pattern";
                    print FILE1 "$NewLine\n";
                    ++$pattern;
                 }
           close(FILE1);     
      }
 close(FILE);
 exit;
```

**OUTPUT**: Generated new file(NewData.txt) with below data.

```
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 1XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  000 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 011 XXX XX   ; }

//       pattern 0
W "tset1";
Pattern 0
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  XXXXXX  110 011 XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  011000  111 011 XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  000000  111 011 XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 1XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  000 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 011 XXX XX   ; }

//       pattern 0
W "tset1";
Pattern 1
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  XXXXXX  110 011 XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  011000  111 011 XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  000000  111 011 XXX XX   ; }
```

**If you want to give input at the time of script execution, please use the below.**

```
#!C:\Strawberry\perl\bin
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

#Getting input file name
my $file = shift;

#just renaming the file

my $newfile = $file.".txt";
move($file,$newfile);
chomp($newfile);

#Opening file to get the required data

my $pattern = 0;
open (FIL, "$newfile");
while (<FIL>) {
       my $CurrentLine = $_;

#Creating new file
       open (FILE1, ">>$file");
       print FILE1 "$CurrentLine";
            if ($_ =~ /tset/) {
                my $NewLine = "Pattern $pattern";
                print FILE1 "$NewLine\n";
                ++$pattern;
             }
       close(FILE1);     
  }
 close(FIL);
 exit;
```

**OUTPUT**: Will be created with the same file name which you have provided at the time of script execution. Here I gave below file name in CMD prompt.

```
>perl pat.pl Data.txt
```

Generated Data.txt file with below output.

```
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 1XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  000 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 011 XXX XX   ; }

//       pattern 0
W "tset1";
Pattern 0
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  XXXXXX  110 011 XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  011000  111 011 XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  000000  111 011 XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 1XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  000 XXX XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = 0XXX0X  XX0XXX  100 011 XXX XX   ; }

//       pattern 0
W "tset1";
Pattern 1
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  XXXXXX  110 011 XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  011000  111 011 XXX XX   ; }
V { allFuncPins = XXXXXX  000000  111 011 XXX XX   ; }
```

Comment: thank you @Amareesh this solved my problem!

just curious, how do I remove the my $file variable and replace it with an option for the script to accept an input parameter, say the file name of this file that I want to modify and not output a new file. it will just edit the existing.

Comment: @SydPao Do you want just to display on the output screen or to capture output in the file? Because solution provided by chris Doyle is just displaying the output, but not writing in to the file.

Comment: @SydPao I have added new piece of code in my answer, please see above.

Comment: thanks @Amareesh... this is savvy. do you know how i can make this script more generic? Like I would like to take the filename as input to the script and it will not generate a new file but just edit the existing? thanks in advance! i am learning by your examples.